# Create a new feature class of a different geometry type using the same schema from an existing feature class

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, schema

I have the data schema for a point feature class that I would like to apply to a new line feature class. That is, I'd like to have all the same fields with the same set domains in the feature class that I had in the old feature class. Is there a way to use an existing feature class of one type (point) as a template for production of a new feature class (line)?

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.9 and ArcGIS Online.

Comment: Use the 'template' argument in Create Feature Class.  https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/create-feature-class.htm

Comment: Thank you @Brennan! I had a feeling it was something just that simple.

Comment: Go ahead an add your comment as an answer if you'd like and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the 'template' argument in Create Feature Class.

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/create-feature-class.htm